# How was the running time calculated for this (selection sort) algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, code-analysis, selection-sort

[Selection sort algorithm from my book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vefT.png)
￼

When analyzing the the running time for this  algorithm, my book used
￼[this formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxS6E.png)

I understand how the inner summation was simplified to *n-1-i*. However, I don’t get this ￼[final step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAQpP.png)
How was it simplified to [(n-1)n]/2?

Answer (score 1):

Sigma(n - 1 - i) = Sigma(n) - Sigma(1) - Sigma (i) = (n-1)*n - (n-1) - (n-2)(n-1)/2

Simplify more and you will get nˆ2/2 - n/2 
Which give n(n-1)/2

Comment: how was sigma(n) simplified?

Comment: Sigma(from i = 0 to n-2) (n) = n + n + .... + n. The number of n's is (n-1) because the number of the iterations of the sigma is (n-1). A loop from 0 to n-2 iterates (n-1) times

Comment: so sigma(n) simplifies to n(n-1)?

Comment: n+n+n = 3*n; n+n+n+n = 4*n; n+n+n+...+n (for n-1 times) = (n-1)*n

Comment: Thank you. why was sigma(i) simplified to (n-2)(n-1)/2? my book says it simplifies to (n-2)(n+1)/2

Comment: No, it does not say that. It says: Sigma (from i=1 to n) (i) = n*(n+1)/2. In other words, the sum equals to the upper limit n multiplied by its successor (n+1) divided by 2. In your case, the upper limit is (n-2) and its successor is (n-1). So, your sigma equals to (n-2)(n-1)/2

Comment: @plantstho Thank you for checking this answer as the answer to your question if it is clear to you.